# Basic Animation (Swipe to turn)

Tags: ios, animation, graphics, opengl-es, core-animation

I am thinking of adding a animation to my Table View. This should work as following: The User swipes over a table view Cell horizontal and the content of the cell turns, so that "the other side of the card" is visible. How could i do that? I have no idea if I e.g. try to do that by making everything by myself with a opengl view in every row, or if i could use CoreAnimation? Are there maybe better ways to do that? How do the professionals realize such animations (e.g. Flipboard)? I don't need source code, a short description or a keyword would help very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has build in functionality. I am currently using it and it works great.

Let's say you have 2 views A and B that you want to flip between. The flip animates the entire area of the parent, so if you only want the flip to be all of A, make sure A and its parent are the same size.

Here is what I like to do to flip back and forth:

```
if(B.superview == nil)
   [UIView transitionFromView:A toView:B duration:1.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:nil];
else 
   [UIView transitionFromView:B toView:A duration:1.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];
```

After the flip, the FromView will be removed from its parent (superview) and the ToView will be added to that parent. You can put the above code in a gesture recognizer for swipe or tap. I only needed tap so I put a clear button inside A and B, and in its button event I called the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a UISwipeGestureRecognizer on your cell and then when swiped use a UIView transition animation. (See UIView Documentation).  Should do what you want.